# CPanel cron job (bad command)

Tags: php, cpanel

I wanted to run a cron job URL every 5 minutes and I am trying the following:

```
*/5 * * * * curl http://ur-views.com/gramlater/queue_processor.php`
```

But I get the following error:

[image: Screenshot of CPanel error]

Comment: Sounds like the original crontab is broken. Your line look ok, maybe make `"` around the url

Answer (score 2):

Remove the */5 * * * * from the command section.

You only need the actual command in there, the bit above handles the frequency that it's executed.